# Looking for a way to compare and count all nested objects key/value pairs in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like:

```
const arr1 = [
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Rachel"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Rachel"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Ross","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Ross","to":"Monica"},
];
```

and I want to sort and count all unique instances where both keys ('from' and 'to') are the same.

I can count successfully each case comparing just one key (either 'from' or 'to') but I can't find a solution on how to compare both.

Here is my sample code:

```
let arr2 = Object.values(arr1.reduce((c, { from, to }) => {
 c[from] = c[from] || { from, to, count: 0 };
 c[from].count++;
 return c;
}, {}));
console.log(arr2);
```

here is the result I get now (as code compares just 'from' key):

```
console.log(arr2);
// Array(2)
// 0: {from: "Monica", to: "Rachel", count: 4}
// 1: {from: "Ross", to: "Chandler", count: 2}
// length: 2
```

and here is the result I want to achieve:

```
console.log(arr2);
// Array(2)
// 0: {from: "Monica", to: "Rachel", count: 2}
// 1: {from: "Monica", to: "Chandler", count: 2}
// 2: {from: "Ross", to: "Chandler", count: 1}
// 3: {from: "Ross", to: "Monica", count: 1}
// length: 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using `Array.reduce`, you can group by the input array by the `from` and `to` variable pairs key.
- And for duplicated, the count will be increased and finally, the result will be stored on the values of each key on `groupedBy` object.
- You can extract values only using `Object.values`.

```js
const arr1 = [
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Rachel"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Rachel"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Ross","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Ross","to":"Monica"},
];

const groupedBy = arr1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const key = `${cur.from}_${cur.to}`;
  acc[key] ? acc[key].count ++ : acc[key] = {
    ...cur,
    count: 1
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(groupedBy);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a combined key of `from` and `to` values with a separator.

```js
const
    array = [{ from: "Monica", to: "Rachel" }, { from: "Monica", to: "Rachel" }, { from: "Monica", to: "Chandler" }, { from: "Monica", to: "Chandler" }, { from: "Ross", to: "Chandler" }, { from: "Ross", to: "Monica" }],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, { from, to }) => {
        const key = [from, to].join('|');
        r[key] ??= { from, to, count: 0 };
        r[key].count++;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop on each object, get it's `from` and `to` values and compare them.

```js
const arr = [
 {"from": "A", "to": "B"},
 {"from": "A", "to": "C"},
 {"from": "A", "to": "A"},
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].from == arr[i].to) {
    console.log('Matches!');
  }
  else {
    console.log('No match');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

1. sort the array by the `from` and `to` combination, after this, the duplicates will be adjacent in the sorted array.
2. iterate through the sorted array to remove duplicates and count.

```js
const arr1 = [
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Rachel"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Rachel"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Monica","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Ross","to":"Chandler"},
 {"from":"Ross","to":"Monica"},
];
 
var arr2 = arr1.sort((obj1, obj2) => (obj1.from + obj1.to).localeCompare(obj2.from + obj2.to));

for(var i = arr2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  if(i > 0 && arr2[i].from + arr2[i].to == arr2[i-1].from + arr2[i-1].to){
     arr2[i-1].count = arr2[i].count ? arr2[i].count + 1 : 2;
     arr2.splice(i, 1);
  }else if(!arr2[i].count){
    arr2[i].count = 1;
  }
}
console.log(arr2);
```